# Backup HDD with multiple partitions and hardware ID licenses

Tags: windows, backup

There is an old computer in a production. It manages specific industrial automation device. It operates on a Windows XP SP1, maybe SP2. It's motherboard may not even support boot up from USB.
Now is the time to make a backup while this system is still alive.

HDD has 3 partitions for 1) system 2) data 3) critical software (hidden).
There are several expensive software solutions installed with the licenses bound to current hardware.

I have several questions bases on this:

- How do I backup an entire HDD?
- Do I need a bigger HDD than the original one to store a backup or is there a "clever" way? Partitions are big, but they are mostly empty.
- What to do with licenses? Most licenses derive from hardware ID, which is based on serial numbers of current motherboard, HDD, etc. I fear that if I switch current HDD to the new one, the system may lose it's activations.

I also thought about complete virtualization: clone entire HDD and run it on a virtual machine on a modern server.

P.S. Generally, I've made backup's via `dd` on a Linux live-cd/usb, but with the possibility of losing this absurdly expensive system by a simple mistake, I want to explore all available options. Thanks.

Comment: Use cloning software like Clonezilla and dump the whole disk to an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to P2V this machine and test how the licenses work in the virtual state. From there you can proceed with other steps.